# Installing ROS2 as Debian package leads to broken install

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic) and I tried to install ROS2 Eloquent using the command

```
sudo apt install ros-eloquent-ros-base
```

When I look into my ros folder, this is what I see

```
me@sirius:/opt/ros/eloquent$ ls
bin  cmake  include  lib  share  src
```

Apparently, the setup scripts are missing. For testing purpose I also installed ROS dashing and here I get

```
me@sirius:/opt/ros/dashing$ ls
bin    include  local_setup.bash  local_setup.zsh     setup.bash  setup.zsh
cmake  lib      local_setup.sh    _order_packages.py  setup.sh    share
```

Did I do something wrong or is the install broken?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356950/installing-ros2-as-debian-package-leads-to-broken-install/) by [eloquent-fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/56547/eloquent-fox/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-07-14**:
Try re-installing? The expected setup.* files are there for me. I don't know what would cause them to be missing.

```
sudo apt remove ros-eloquent-ros-base
```

```
sudo apt install ros-eloquent-ros-base
```

**Comment by [eloquent-fox](https://answers.ros.org/users/56547/eloquent-fox/) on 2020-07-29**:
Thank you, indeed it seemed something went wrong during installation, after running

```
sudo apt remove ros-eloquent-* && sudo apt autoremove
```

and install again, the setup scripts are here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The setup files are installed by the package `ros-eloquent-ros-workspace` which is a dependency of `ros-eloquent-ros-base` If you don't have those files I suspect that you didn't successfully install what you thought that you installed. Please edit your question to show the full output of your apt commands so we can help you more.

Also useful would be to show the output of `dpkg -l ros-eloquent-*`

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0